# web scraping vaadin python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, vaadin

I'm trying to scrape a site created using vaadin using python. This is the code I use:

```
requests.get('http://rnb.osim.ro/?pn=').text
```

but this is the result which contains no useful information:

```
    <noscript>
    You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.
   </noscript>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<!
```

Do you know how I can get the data I need from a vaadin site?

Comment: The default scraping method of Python will only look at the source code at a basic level - if the page itself has a system to check the requirements of the website is met before loading, it will almost always fail when additional scripting is required. Best bet (IMO) would be to use Chromium to open the site in an automated page using Chrome and scrape it from there.

This advice is based on what you've given - but your py script would be helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `requests` can't really execute the JavaScript inside the website. As you might think, `requests` is just a request and not a browser that can handle JS and work with frameworks for the front end (i.e. Angular, React, Ajax). To scrape this modern and robust websites I personally recommend to use `scrapy` library. It's designed specially for scraping and can handle with the JavaScript a little bit. And even if it couldn't, you can still use the `selenium web driver` to fully emulate a browser.

Comment: I have tried to use selenium web driver once on my vaadin flow app. Because almost everything uses shadow DOM, I quickly gave it up again. However I have *no* experience with selenium web driver so it may be that my failure was my fault alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with requests, you may also find [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) useful. If your just want to get the rendered html and not interact with the page, like clicking buttons, page-down etc. then you can use this option.

Your question is ideal for this demonstration. The following code fully renders the html you want.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://rnb.osim.ro/?pn=')
r.html.render(sleep = 5)
print(r.html.html)
```